# from: can't read /var/mail/django.utils.version when running django-admin.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to install Django v3.0.6 (or any other v3.x.y) in my macOS. Following are the steps that I've done:

- installed python3 using homebrew, then ran `sudo pip3 install virtualenv`,
- navigating into my target project folder, ran `virtualenv venv -p python3`.
- After activating it, ran `pip install Django==3.0.6`. This resulted in a successful installation of Django 3.0.6.

However, when I run `django-admin.py startproject myproject` I immediately get the following error:

```
from: can't read /var/mail/django.utils.version
/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py: line 3: `VERSION = (3, 0, 6, 'final', 0)'
```

Trying to to run this `django-admin.py` command using the virtualenv is actually my second attempt. I initially started trying with installing Django directly in my machine, not using virtualenv, which also resulted in the same error. My assumption is that happened because the default python version in my machine/OS is 2.7. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the complete path of your django-admin.py from your virtualenv.

```
/absolute-path/venv/bin/django-admin startproject myproject
```

Comment: thank you so much. Not exactly sure why it needs the absolute path, but it works!

Comment: on second thoughts, while this fixed the problem for the time being, any idea what would be a fix to make it so that I can only use `django-admin` and not prepending the full directory? @upendra243